# Ctrl+L on terminal doesn't work anymore

Tags: 14.04, command-line, kde

Usually on the command line you could write <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and this would clean the command line, but now it doesn't. The command does nothing at all. How can I restore it to the way it was?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bits with KDE.

Comment: Which terminal? Konsole? Yakuake? GNOME Terminal?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. The terminal is Konsole.

Comment: Try to put `"\C-l": clear-screen` line inside `~/.inputrc` file